# How to override child element of default paramter in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have following parameter set in role/downloader/defaults/main.yml

```
download:
  location: "/tmp/download"
  file: "EXAMPLE.tar.gz"
  url: "http://<url>/repo//"
  file_permission: '755'
  checksum: md5:e207d015e0a435193afbc82e15bba19c 
  force_download: False
```

And in another role I tried to override few parameter like below

```
meta/main.yml
    ---
    dependencies:
      - role: downloader
        vars:
          download:
            file: LINUX_X86-64.tar.gz
            location: "/tmp/download"
```

But it resulted in disctionary value undefined error. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're interested in `default_hash_behavior` setting, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour.

I can't help with an example as I haven't used before.

However, I have seen recommendations for keeping variables separated basically for this reason.

For example, instead of defining the variable as a hash,

```
download:
  location: "/tmp/download"
  file: "EXAMPLE.tar.gz"
```

it may be simpler to make each a unique variable.

```
download_location: "/tmp/download"
download_file: "EXAMPLE.tar.gz"
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** As suggested from the link at the top of my post, perhaps the `combine` filter could also solve this for you: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries

Comment: Thanks for reply....I thought group similar parameter under one dictionary is good for readability...Do you think defining paramter  separately is best practice to be followed ?

Comment: I agree that dictionary looks better, but we ran into similar issues as you. Declaring each as a separate variable seemed like a simple solution and has worked for us so far. Not sure which is best practice - but it's simple and it works :)

Comment: I changed hash_behaviour=merge in ansible.cfg which resolved the issue. Do you know the impact of this change?

Comment: Well, now all hashes are merged - instead of being overwritten - when defined twice. So just something to be aware of. Could cause unexpected outcomes if you forget the new behavior.